# Rabbit mq handshake_timeout

Tags: networking, python, docker, rabbitmq

There is a rabbitmq running on docker on my ubuntu aws server, which I connect to from my local pc app. After setting up https domain on nginx, it broke up (I am not sure if it the reason).

I tried to connect via `telnet ip port` which shows `Connection closed by foreign host.`
Docker logs after above command:

```
2020-10-02 17:20:57.873 [info] <0.546.0> Resetting node maintenance status
2020-10-02 17:31:23.071 [info] <0.1670.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.1670.0> (84.54.87.17:58935 -> private_ip:5672)
2020-10-02 17:31:23.071 [error] <0.1670.0> closing AMQP connection <0.1670.0> (84.54.87.17:58935 -> private_ip:5672):
{handshake_timeout,handshake}
```

Interestingly, the same error occurs when I connect to rabbit_management plugin via telnet.
But, i am able to access rabbit_management from browser.

Aws bounding rules and ufw ports are open

When run my app (python and aio_pika lib for rabbitmq client) following error occurs:

```
Could not get addresses to use: [Errno -2] Name or service not known (http)
```

How to fix this?

P.S. I use elastic ip to connect to rabbit, not domain name. But it should work in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was regarding the protocol. In my case as I blocked out incoming http requests, the http://ip was invalid request url, which should be changed to `ip` without http protocol.